# How to find a number greater than the largest (smaller than the smallest) eigen value of a matrix efficiently?

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

I have a symmetric matrix $A$, I want to find a number say $\lambda_1$ which is greater than $\lambda$,i.e. the largest eigen value of the matrix $A$.
It doesn't need to be equal to $\lambda$. But it's needed to be as fast as possible and of course no so much greater than.

What is the efficient method to find such a number, $\lambda_1 \geq \lambda$?

Comment: You could use $1$ more than the sum of the absolute values of the entries.  But this might be much larger than $\lambda$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the Gershgorin circle theorem. Which in this case amounts to one of the $\infty$ or $1$-norms.

For every eigenvalue $\lambda$ there is a row $k$ such that
$$
|λ-a_{kk}|\le \sum_{j\ne k}|a_{kj}|\implies λ\le \max_{k}\sum_{j}|a_{kj}|
$$
and the same for the transpose of the matrix.

If you have the time, it is relatively easy and fast to transform the matrix into Hessenberg form. In general, this should give tighter bounds.

Comment: How to tight is this upperbound? Actually, I want the smallest eigen value of the matrix which is negative, It seems that it is possible to use greshgorin theorem for it. Correct? How to transform matrix into Hessenberg form, and what is it's complexity?

Comment: Similar to the QR decomposition, you can use Householder reflections or Givens rotations. The effort is $n-2$ reflections applied from both sides of the matrix, i.e. about 2 QR decompositions. -- And yes, in the first formulation you can establish an interval for the eigenvalues which may be better than the symmetric interval provided by the norms.

Comment: Transforming to Hessenberg form is $O(n^2)$ or $O(n^3)$? Is it faster than methods for finding dominant eigen value? Thank you very much.

Comment: $O(n^3)$. Note that power iteration is $O(n^2|\log\epsilon|)$ at best.